# Getting the results from a stored procedure in Web Matrix

Tags: webmatrix

How do you get the results of a stored procedure in WebMatrix?  db.Execute is only giving me the int result code, and db.Query doesn't find the column name in the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Database helper uses the default CommandType, which is CommandType.Text. There is no way to change that to CommandType.StoredProcedure, so you need to use the following syntax:

```
var data = db.Query("exec usp_MyProc @0, @1", "val1", val2");
```

The target audience for WebMatrix are not assumed to know about stored procedures. But you can always use plain ADO.NET and populate a strongly typed object via a SqlDataReader. Or the Entity Framework....

Comment: I use it because the syntax is easier. I prefer shorter code. But I guess sometimes advanced code needs to be somewhat larger.